# Do I need a certificate from google if my android-app is just inhouse?

Tags: android, deployment, certificate, in-house-distribution

I don't want to deploy it in the play store. The deployement process shout be mail or by http (click by link) or later by MDM, and there will be no need ever for deploying the app in to the store. Do i need a certificate for this purpose? As an IOS-App i would say yes but on Android side it's different is it?

regards && tia
  noircc

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to request a Certificate from google to publish to the Play Store.

**But:** You will have to create a Certificate and sign your app because only signed apps can be installed.

So, yes, you do need a Certificate, but you have to create it yourself. Read details on how to create a certificate and how sign your app here: [App Signing](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Android deployment is far easier then with the iOS Apps. If you are using Eclipse as IDE, you can just follow the instructions in the menu to export your App. The only thing you will have to do is create a keystore, which will be used when you create updates for your Apps.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't there are no restrictions if your distribute your app in any other way than through the play store. I don't know what you exactly mean by certificate, but when you release your app you sign it with your own certificate.